# Permission Error on heroku using ffmpeg and discord.py

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg, discord.py

```
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.player import FFmpegPCMAudio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()


class Voice(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client


    @commands.command(name = 'join')
    async def join(self,ctx):
        
        in_vc = ctx.author.voice
        if in_vc is None:

            await ctx.send('Please join a vc')

        else:

            vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
            await vc.connect()
            source = FFmpegPCMAudio(executable = r'.\FFmpeg\ffmpeg.exe', source = r'.\Audio\audio.mp3')
            print(source)
            ctx.voice_client.play(source)
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()



def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Voice(client))
```

This is the code I'm using to play an audio file in a discord voice channel

This code works fine locally on my Windows Machine
But when I deployed this on Heroku and ran the same command

It came up with this permission error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
 discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './FFmpeg/ffmpeg.exe'
```

Buildpacks I'm using:

heroku/python,

https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git

Comment: This is because Heroku can't access files on your computer. You need to add the FFMPEG buildpack.

Comment: @Dominik I'm using this https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git FFMPEG buildpack for Heroku.
Still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Have you also added the Opus buildpack? What does still not work?

Comment: After adding the Opus buildpack it's working
Thnaks a lot for your help